# What is the name of the printer config app

Tags: command-line, printing

I want to be able to configure my printer by starting the printer configuration app from the command line.  What is its name?

I'm running Ubuntu 18,but I'm not running Gnome (Xmonad instead), thus I can't get to the app via the usual [route outlined in the documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/printing-setup.html.en).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my 18.04 64 bit system with LXDE desktop, it's `system-config-printer`.